# gulp не копирует суто файлы

Tags: gulp

Вопрос немного странный, но всё же я не смог найти ответ.
Нужно найти все картинки, далее с ними проводятся определённые действия и скопировать их в другую папку, но вместо того чтобы скопировать суто картинку, он создаёт папку с названием родительской для неё папки и вставляет туда картинку. Пример ниже

```js
const SRC_DIR  = './src/';
const DIST_DIR = './public/';

let path = {
  image_build: {
        src : `${SRC_DIR}assets/common/block/commonBlocks/**/**/*.+(jpg|png|gif|svg)`,
        dist: `${DIST_DIR}img/`
  }
}

gulp.task('image:build', () => {
    gulp.src(path.image_build.src)
    .pipe(imagemin({
        progressive: true,
        svgoPlugins: [{removeViewBox: false}],
        use: [pngquant()],
        interlaced: true
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.image_build.dist))
    .pipe(reload({stream: true}));
});

gulp.task('fonts:build', () => {
    gulp.src(path.fonts_build.src)
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.fonts_build.dist))
});
```

Картинка до копирования:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Картинка после копирования:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужны суто картинки

Comment: А что означает слово `суто`? Сюда?

Comment: Нашёл выход, просто использовать gulp-flatten. https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-flatten

Comment: И все-таки что значит слово - `суто` ? Это по-каковски? Ну, т.е. такого слова в русском языке нет.